# ConcurrentHashMap putIfAbsent first time

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, concurrent-programming

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` and a method that puts a String in the map, then I do some actions in a synchronized block based on the inserted value.

`putIfAbsent` *returns the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key* - based on the official documentation

There are 2 actions that are executed based on whether `putIfAbsent` returns null or not.

Now here is the trick. I want the first action (when `putIfAbsent` returns null) to be executed first and all other threads to be put on hold.
My code works as intended 95% of the time.

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> logins = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void login(String id){
      String inserted=logins.putIfAbsent(id,id);

      synchronized(logins.get(id)){
           if(inserted==null){
                System.out.println("First login");
           }else{
                System.out.println("Second login");
           }           
      }
}
```

If I call this method with the same String value from different threads `login("some_id");` sometimes (around 5% of the time) I get this message on console:

```
Second login
First login
```

What do I need to change to always be sure that `First login` is executed first?

**Update**: From what I read is it possible that logins.get(id) return null , therefore synchronizing on a null object?

Comment: logins.putIfAbsent(id,id) ,and your synchronized block statements are not atomic . That's why  sometimes the second login is executed first. Also it is not good idea to synchronize on string literals

Comment: Should `map` be `logins` ?

Comment: @MichaelEaster yes. sorry I modified the code

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes (around 5% of the time) I get this message on console:

You have a race condition that the first to add is not the first to print.

In this case, your main bottleneck is the using System.out, this is a contented resource which is many times more expensive than using a Map, concurrent or otherwise.

In which case, you may as well simplify your code so you are only obtaining one lock which is the lock on `System.out` which you have to obtain anyway

```
// use System.out as lock so logging of actions is always in order.
private final Set<String> ids = Collections.newSetFromMap(new HashMap<>());

public void login(String id) {
    synchronized (System.out) {
        System.out.println(ids.add(id) ? "First login" : "Second login")l
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> logins= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> locks= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


public void login(String id){

locks.putIfAbsent(id,new Object());
Object lock = locks.get(id);
synchronized(lock)
{
      String inserted=logins.putIfAbsent(id,id);

           if(inserted==null){
                System.out.println("First login");
           }else{
                System.out.println("Second login");
           }           

}
}
```

Note: Also make sure that you remove the entries from hashmaps when the id is deleted

or Use some other field(apart from string id)  to synchronize the code

Answer (score 0):

Java offers other synchronization mechanisms that offer more granularity, and IMO, clarity.

Consider the code below. The code illustrates (a) how to protect multiple operations with a lock (b) how the `then` and `else` sections can be handled differently (e.g. `then` protects functions with the lock; `else` assumes that functions do not require protection. Alter as appropriate for your situation):

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    private String id;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> logins;
    private Lock lock;

    public Task(String id, ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> logins, Lock lock) {
        this.id = id;
        this.logins = logins;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run() {
        login(id);
    }

    public void login(String id){
        lock.lock();

        String inserted = logins.putIfAbsent(id,id);

        if (inserted==null) {
            System.out.print("First login ");
            // other functions that require synchronization
            lock.unlock();
        } else {
            lock.unlock();
            // functions that do NOT require synchronization
            System.out.print("Second login ");
        }           
    }
}
```